# Configuration of TCP/IP with SSL and TLS for Oracle

Tags: oracle, ssl, tls-1.2

I am trying to configure the connections to my Oracle database with tcp / ip using ssl I have been guided by the procedure of the site https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/configure-tcpip-with-ssl-and-tls-for-database-connections site in which I have learned a lot, but nevertheless this procedure after configuring everything without apparent problems shows me the error ORA-29106: Can not import PKCS # 12 wallet. Please, I need help, thank you very much.

Comment: 4 digit version and Edition?

Comment: I'm using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: There is no chance to use TLS1.2 with Oracle 11.2.0.3. You need at least 11.2.0.4 the latest PSU and maybe one more oneoff patch.

Comment: But this error also comes to me with a database 12c doing the same site procedure